# Taking the argument by && in std::vector push_back() and std::map operator[]

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, stl, reference

I found this in std::vector::push_back() implementation:

```
void push_back(_Ty&& _Val)
{
    // some code here       
}
```

and this in std::map operator[] implementation:

```
mapped_type& operator[](key_type&& _Keyval)
{
    // some code here   
}
```

Why _Val and _Keyval is taking by the reference-by-reference? How does the taking of the argument by reference-by-reference working? What are the benefits of this approach in comparison with the taking by reference?

P.S. This is NOT the logical "AND", I understand this clearly.

Comment: read manual: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

Comment: I think this reference may the right to exist, although it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a C++11 feature - rvalue references...  Here's some more [info](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html)